# Assigning a unique id in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
$ var Node = function(){ this.someval = 0; }
undefined
$ var node = new Node();
undefined
$ node.someval
0
$ Node.next_id = 0
0
$ Node.prototype.constructor = function() { this.someval = Node.next_id++; }
function () { this.someval = Node.next_id++; }
$ var node2 = new Node();
undefined
$ node2.someval
0
$ var node3 = new Node();
undefined
$ node3.someval
0
```

Why doesn't next_id++ work as expected? I expected next_id to increment with every call to `new Node()` and thus assign a new id to each node.

Comment: Setting the "constructor" property of the "prototype" object does not do what you appear to imagine it does.

Comment: `Node.prototype.constructor = function() { this.someval = Node.next_id++; }` does not automagically change `Node`.

Comment: I see, so I have to say var Node = function() { this.someval = Node.next_id++; }

Answer (score 3):

There's no special behavior associated with `Node.prototype.constructor`. Setting it to some value has no side effect, other than the assignment.

You could give it whatever value you want:

```
Node.prototype.constructor = "foobar";
```

...and there will be no modification to the `Node` constructor. In other words, it's just a plain old circular reference.

---

To do what you want, do the increment in the constructor.

```
var Node = function(){ this.someval = Node.next_id++; };

Node.next_id = 0;
```

---

You should also note that there's nothing special about assigning a property to the `Node` constructor.

```
Node.foo = "bar"; // doesn't impact the behavior of the constructor
```

All it does is add a property to the function object, but it has absolutely no impact on the objects constructed via the `Node` constructor.

So what you're doing is using the `Node` function object as a namespace. This is fine, but I would personally use a closure instead.

```
var Node = (function() {

    var next_id = 0;

    return function Node() { this.someval = next_id++; };

})();
```

This makes `next_id` inaccessible to any code outside the immediately invoked function, giving it some protection from external modification. It's a very common pattern.

```
var node2 = new Node();
node2.someval; // 0

var node3 = new Node();
node3.someval; // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Console is showing correct value of this.someval.
as in case of `this.someval = Node.next_id++` value of `Node.next_id` will be assigned to `this.someval` then it will increment value of `Node.next_id`.

try :

```
  > var i = 0; //undefined
  > var j = i++; //undefined
  > i; //1
  > j;//0
```

`function() { this.someval = Node.next_id++; }` would get called while you creating a new instance of Node

use following code:

```
var Node = function(){ this.someval = Node.next_id++; }
Node.next_id = 0;
var node2 = new Node();
node2.somval // 0;
Node.next_id // 1
```